# Is it possible to have Kendo Context Menu (right click menu) on Kendo Treelist?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, treelist

I have a Kendo Treelist and now I want to add custom Context Menu on it (right click menu) on it. Things I have tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {           
    $("#menu").kendoContextMenu({
        // listen to right-clicks on treelist container
        target: "#treelist",
        // show when node text is clicked
        filter: "tr",
        // handle item clicks        
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works. Your code is right. [See it here](http://dojo.telerik.com/EMIMu/2)